# Problem with entering string when using cin.ignore() in C++

Tags: c++

I have a big problem with cin.ignore() for days.
This is my code excerpt, not all

```
string ID;
cin.ignore(100,'\n');
cout << "Enter User ID: " << endl;
getline(cin, ID);
```

The problem is, when I use `cin.ignore()` like this, I have to enter the string ID twice to continue but when i don't use it, I can not enter the string anymore. I completely dont know why, hope someone can explain it!

Comment: What do you think `cin.ignore(100,'\n')` does? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: As per your code snippet, cin.ignore() will ignore 100 characters until \n(Enter) is pressed. So you probably press enter before inputting ID.                                        ```                                                                                                                                int main()
{
   string ID;
   cin.ignore(100, '\n');
   cin >> ID;
   cout << "string:" << ID;
   return 0;
}                                                                                                                                             ```

Comment: I'm betting you can find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567291/6865932

Comment: So it seems highly relevant that you show the previous code. Taken in isolation there is no need for ignore in the code above. But you say your code does not work without it either. So we need to see more code. Try to construct a [mre].